# Find: missing argument to `-execdir'

Tags: windows, bash, shell, git-bash

[image]

I'm working in win 10 with git-bash. I have a large group of files all of which have no extension. However I've realized that those of type "File" are html files. To select these I have been shown:

```
$ find -not -name '*.*'
```

Now I need to rename all these files to add a .html extension (they currently have no extension). I've tried :

```
$ find -not -name '*.*' -execdir mv {} {}.html
find: missing argument to `-execdir'
```

How can I rename these files?

Comment: `;` or `+` at the end is mandatory.

Comment: Also note that `{}.html` isn't guaranteed by the POSIX standard for `find` to work at all. `{}` is only mandated to be honored as a separate word, not a substring, so the substring case may or may not work depending on your implementation.

Comment: If he's doing this on Windows, POSIX isn't really relevant, it's almost certainly GNU find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `;` -- a literal semicolon passed to signal the end of the arguments parsed as part of the `-exec` action. Accepting such a terminator lets `find` accept other actions following `-exec`, whereas otherwise any action in that family would need to be the very last argument on the command line.

```
find -not -name '*.*' -execdir mv -- '{}' '{}.html' ';'
```

---

That said, note that the above isn't guaranteed to work at all (or to work with names that start with dashes). More portable would be:

```
find . -not -name '*.*' -exec sh -c 'for arg do mv -- "$arg" "$arg.html"; done' _ {} +
```

Note the changes:

- The `.` specifying the directory to start the search at is mandatory in POSIX-standard `find`; the ability to leave it out on GNU platforms is a nonportable extension.
- Running an explicit shell means you don't need `{}.html` to be supported, and so can work with any compliant `find`.
- The `--` ensures that the following arguments are parsed as literal filenames, not options to `mv`, even if they start with dashes.
- In the above, the explicit `_` becomes `$0` of the shell, so later arguments become `$1` and onward -- ie. the array otherwise known as `"$@"`, which `for` iterates over by default.

Comment: Thank you , it did work but I noticed that directories were also renamed to have a .html extension. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Put in a `-type f` to filter for files, or `-not -type d` to only exclude directories.